# How does the outcome of measurement of a qubit change when we use different basis despite the system hasn't changed?

Tags: quantum-state, measurement, textbook-and-exercises, hadamard

Let's assume that the quantum state of the system is written in a standard basis {$|0\rangle, |1\rangle$} and when we performed a measurement we got $|0\rangle$ as an outcome of measurement so we ensure that the system will be in state $|0\rangle$ after measurement even if we make this measurement (in this basis) many times.

My question is, how we get something else than $|0\rangle$ {$|+\rangle$ or $|-\rangle$} when we are measuring in different basis {$|+\rangle, |-\rangle$} despite we didn't change the system?

Comment: Please do a text copy-paste and ping me in a reply comment. I will fix it and give a reopen vote.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica I can't clearly understand what do you mean by text copy-paste. However, I will copy my question:
Based on the example above, let's assume that the quantum state of the system is written in a standard basis {|0⟩,|1⟩} and when we performed a measurement we got |0⟩ as an outcome of measurement so we ensure that the system will be in state |0⟩ after measurement even if we make this measurement (in this basis) many times.
My question is, how we get something else than |0⟩ {|+⟩ or |−⟩} when we are measuring in different basis {|+⟩,|−⟩} despite we didn't change the system?

Comment: Screenshots are highly unwelcomed network-wide. This is why you got downs and this is why your question was closed. You can read the details [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1783163) (that is an MSO content, but the reasons of the QC SE are the same). I offered to make your formulas proper here, but I did not offer to manually type your image as text.

Comment: Btw, the reason that your question was not deleted on the spot is that it is anyways good (and also its answer). My reason to fix it, is the same.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica I checked the link and now I can understand why images are not the best way to explain my question. Thank you for the link. I deleted it, I think my question is clear also without it.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica I removed the image so I don't know why my question is still closed!

Comment: It already has 3 reopen votes, after 5 it will be reopened. If the reopen votes don't arrive, they will timeout, as far I know, 1 per week. You have now 171 rep, from 250 also you will see that (on your own question - on the questions of others it will need 500).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a postulate of quantum mechanics that any device that measures a two-state quantum system (a qubit) must have two preferred states $\{|e_1\rangle, |e_2\rangle \}$ that form an orthonormal basis for the associated vector space (here would be $\mathbb{C}^2$).

A measurement on the state $|\psi\rangle$ transforms $|\psi\rangle$ into one of the these basis vectors $|e_1 \rangle$ or $|e_2\rangle$. The probability that the state $|\psi\rangle$ is measured as $|e_1\rangle$ or $|e_2\rangle$ is the square of the magnitude of the amplitude of the component of the state in the direction of the basis vector  $|e_1\rangle$ or $|e_2\rangle$ . Hence the name projection.

[image]

If you are in the state $|+\rangle$ and your measurement is in the computational basis, $\{ |0\rangle, |1\rangle \}$, then the probability of observing the state $|0\rangle$ is the magnitude square of the component of the projected vector. When you project the vector $|+\rangle$ onto the vector $|0\rangle$ you get the vector $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|0\rangle$. Thus the probability of observing the state $|0\rangle$ is $|1/\sqrt{2}|^2 = \dfrac{1}{2}$. Similarly, $|+\rangle$ can be projected to $|1\rangle$ and the resultant vector is $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|1\rangle$, hence the probability of observing $|1\rangle$ is also $\dfrac{1}{2}$.

However, if you measure in the basis $\{|+\rangle, |-\rangle \}$ then the projection of $|+\rangle$ onto itself is itself. That is $|+\rangle$ will be just transforms to $|+\rangle$. Thus the probability of observing $|+\rangle$ as $|+\rangle$ in the basis $\{|+\rangle, |-\rangle \}$ is 1.

From here we can see that the notion of *superposition* is **basis-dependent**. All states are superposition with respect to some bases but not with respect to others. That is, a state $|\psi \rangle = \alpha |0\rangle + \beta |1\rangle$ is only a superposition with respect to the  computational basis $\{|0\rangle, |1\rangle \}$ but not a superposition with respect to the bases $\{ \alpha |0\rangle + \beta |1\rangle, \beta^* |0\rangle - \alpha^* |1\rangle \}$.

Since measuring a superposition state $|\psi \rangle =  \alpha |0\rangle + \beta |1\rangle$ is probabilisitc, it is tempted to say that the state $|\psi \rangle$ is a probabilistic mixture of $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ and we just don't know which, when in fact, $|\psi \rangle$ is actually a definite state. That is, if we measure $|\psi\rangle$ in certain bases, we will get a deterministic result.

Comment: Thanks! If quantum system is in state |+⟩ and our device measuring only basis {|0⟩,|1⟩} so it makes sense to me to not observe |0⟩ nor |1⟩, we can observe only |+⟩ with probability 1 in case of our device measuring in basis {|+⟩,|-⟩} but if our device measuring in basis  {|0⟩,|1⟩} we shouldn't observe anything.
So, the question here is why a measurement on the state |ψ⟩ transforms |ψ⟩ into one of the these basis vectors |e1⟩ or |e2⟩ (preferred states) and not to the basis vectors of the state itself?

Comment: @IslamAbdeen If the state is $|+\rangle$ and we measure in the computational basis $\{ |0\rangle, |1\rangle \}$ then we will see both $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ since the state $|+\rangle$ compose/made-up from some component of the state $|0\rangle$ and some component of the state $|1\rangle$. See the pic I have above. Note that this **behavior of measurement** is a postulate/axiom of quantum mechanics. It is not derivable or proof from other physical principles. It is derived from observation of experiments with measuring devices.